# Full rank square sub-matrices of a real unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Can anyone please show a proof for the following:

### _________________________

Given the upper $m\times n$ block $U^{m\times n}$ of a real $n\times n$ **unitary** matrix $U^{n\times n}$, prove that:

(**a**)  there always exist in $U^{m\times n}$ a subset of $m$ linearly independent *(non zero)* columns  *(not necessary consecutive)*,

(**b**)  such subset is always unique / may not be unique ?

### _________________________

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Think about ranks and the relation between row-rank and column-rank.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I am still not clear how to answer the second question: at what conditions there can exist several such subsets of full rank, if ever?

Comment: Do you see any reason why such a set should be unique? Think about the case $m=1$.

Comment: Right, plain simple. Thank you.

Comment: May I ask though just one more thing: can there for some chance exist any criteria to determine how many such subsets of full rank are there for $1<m<n$, based on some properties of the outer unitary matrix, (or even to define them) without simply trying them all? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think that there are simple criteria. Generically, any $m$-element subset is linearly independent, but for specific examples many different behaviours seem to be possible. Basically it is a question of "relative position" between the orthonormal basis formed by the column vectors of your matrix and the subspace $\mathbb C^m\subset\mathbb C^n$ spanned by the first $m$ unit vectors.